# Symfony2 single form to add multiple entries to database at once

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony

I have an Entity

```
class User
{
  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
  protected $id;

  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=17)
    */
    protected $mac;

  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
    */
    protected $sensor;

  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=4)
    */
    protected $sensitivity;

/** getters and setters **/
}
```

in the database every user should have three entries because of three different sensors and I need to create a form to add new user with those sensor names ($sensor) and their sensitivities. Is it possible to do this with a single form? Inputs of the form should be to enter mac (text), sensor1 (number), sensor2 (number), sensor2 (number). Is it possible to do this with a single form? How?

Comment: You wish to store multiple sensors numbers into one column (serialized) and make a form that will handle that ?

Comment: it should be multiple entries (rows) in the database with the same mac but different sensor and sensitivity

Comment: You may create a collection of user in your form with defaults empty value (since you only want X rows to be saved per user. see https://gist.github.com/Venzon/8694089). This will be a collection without need of prototype (sort of static collection).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so what I've done is created the form with all needed inputs using the `createFormBuilder()` without providing an Entity. Then I created a new object `$user = new User();` and then:

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
  $user->setMac($form['mac']->getData());
  $user->setSensor('wiliboxas1');
  $user->setSensitivity($form['sensor1']->getData());
  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();
  $em->clear();
  $user->setSensor('sensor2');
  $vartotojas->setSensitivity($form['sensor2']->getData());
  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();
  $em->clear();

  //and so on..
```

`$em->clear()` is also needed because otherwise it will add only a single entry.